# how to assign file name to match directory file name in jsp/html

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

i want to create an interface for student project where student will input his/her index number,semester and year. When the index number matches the file name in src, the system should preview the pdf file. Below are my codes;

```
<% 
                String indexNum = request.getParameter("txtIndext");
                String term = request.getParameter("cboTerm");
                String yr = request.getParameter("cboYear");
                String file_name = indexNum+"_"+term+"_"+yr;

            if(request.getParameter("btnPreview") !=null){

                %>

                <embed src='textFiles/<%=file_name%>.pdf' height="550" width="1100" type="Application/pdf">
                <%
            }
            %>
```

Please what am i doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Are you sure your TTP request is OK? Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for adding the exception generated. Please here is the exception i get;

Comment: WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:251)
 at org.apache.jsp.academic_jsp._jspService(academic_jsp.java:148)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)

Comment: Thanks seniors, it is finally working. I changed "txtIndex" to "txtIndexNum". Also, i realized that the text inputs were placed outside the "form". Maybe the corrections i made may help others. Thanks once again.